# FAIL Logarithms

Tags: logarithms, fake-proofs

$$\log_11^x=x$$
$$\log_11^y=y$$
$$1^x=1^y\implies\log_11^x=\log_11^y$$
$$\therefore x=y$$
But
$$1^7=1^8\implies7=8$$
Where is my error? And why?

Comment: This is almost the same as deducing that $1=2$ from the fact that $1\cdot0=2\cdot0$.

Comment: $$\log_1 x = \frac{\log x}{\log 1} = \frac{\log x}0 .$$

Comment: Thnxx Stephen. XXX

Comment: One of the properties of logarithms is that $$\log_wx=\frac{\log_qx}{\log_qs}$$
therefore $$\log_1 x = \frac{\log x}{\log 1} = \frac{\log x}0$$ and division by 0 is undefined. Therefore $\log_1x$ is nonsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logarithm function $\log_a$ is typically defined to be the inverse function of the exponential $a^x$. This makes sense for $a > 0$ and $a \ne 1$ since the exponential function is strictly increasing.

But $1^x$ is constant, and so doesn't have an inverse. Therefore, $\log_1$ doesn't really make sense, and it certainly can't be expected to have the same rule as usual logarithms.

Comment: WONDERFUL!!!!!!

Comment: t bongers can you also add this to your answer $\log_1 x = \frac{\log x}{\log 1} = \frac{\log x}0$

Comment: @user112724 Feel free to add another answer to the question if you'd like.

Comment: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking.

Comment: One of the properties of logarithms is that $$\log_wx=\frac{\log_qx}{\log_qs}$$
therefore $$\log_1 x = \frac{\log x}{\log 1} = \frac{\log x}0$$ and division by 0 is undefined. Therefore $\log_1x$ is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

One of the properties of logarithms is that $$\log_wx=\frac{\log_qx}{\log_qs}$$
therefore $$\log_1 x = \frac{\log x}{\log 1} = \frac{\log x}0$$ and division by 0 is undefined. Therefore $\log_1x$ is nonsense.